# Assert headers from response array

Tags: node.js, request, cypress

I want to assert headers[image] from response in cypress but it is giving an error while running a test

Error :::   assertexpected { Object (content-security-policy, expect-ct, ...) } to have property text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

I have tried with below code

```
describe("Assert header in response",function(){
    
beforeEach(function(){
    cy.fixture("datainfixturefile").then(function(data){
        this.data= data
        var base=this.data.dcode
    })
})

    it.only('Valid Request',function(){
        cy.request('POST',this.data.BaseURL+this.data.ValidReq).then((response) =>
        {
           expect(response).to.have.property('status',200);
           expect(response.body).contains('APP-');
           expect(response.headers).to.have.property("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1");
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to specify the key as well as the value

```js
expect(response).to.have.property('status', 200)
expect(response.headers).to.have.property('content-type', 'text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1')
```

See [method property](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property)

> **.property(name[, val[, msg]])**
>
> - @param { String } name
> - @param { Mixed } val (optional)
> - @param { String } msg *optional*
>
> Asserts that the target has a property with the given key name

Comment: yes i have used the same but no luck

Comment: can you try with `expect(response.headers).to.have.property('content-type','text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1');`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.to.have.property`, you can use bracket notation to select a key from the `headers` object.

```js
cy.request('POST',this.data.BaseURL+this.data.ValidReq).then((response) => {
  expect(response.headers['content-type']).to.eql('text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1');
});
```

Additionally, as Krishna pointed out, the correct key for `Content-Type` is `content-type`.

Comment: thanks agoff and  Krishna Majgaonkar, both solution worked for me